# Input not registering from ComPort

Tags: windows, batch-file, arduino, serial-port

Okay now this one really stumps me. I am using an Arduino and Distance sensor to make certain things on my computer happen. What I am doing on my arduino is when my hand is with in a certain distance output a 1 to COM4. Here is my Arduino code

```
#define trigPin 12
#define echoPin 13
#define voltage 11
void setup() {
  pinMode(trigPin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(echoPin, INPUT);
  pinMode(voltage, OUTPUT);
  Serial.begin(115200);
}

void loop() {
  digitalWrite(voltage, HIGH);
  long duration, distance;
  digitalWrite(trigPin, LOW);
  delayMicroseconds(2); 
  digitalWrite(trigPin, HIGH);
  delayMicroseconds(10); 
  digitalWrite(trigPin, LOW);  distance = (duration/2) / 29.1;

  duration = pulseIn(echoPin, HIGH);
  distance = (duration/2) / 29.1;
  if (distance > 18) {
    int var = 0;
    Serial.print(var);
  } else {
    int var = 1;
    Serial.print(var);
  }
}
```

I have a Batch file that then reads COM4 and then does something if the input is 1. Here is the Batch code

```
@echo off
set var=0
echo "hi"
mode COM4 BAUD=115200 PARITY=n DATA=8
:start
set "key="
for /F "delims=" %%K in ('xcopy /W "%~F0" "%~F0" ^< COM4 2^> NUL') do (
   if not defined key set "key=%%K"
)
set /P "line=" < COM4
set "line=%key:~-1%"
echo %line%
if "%line%" == "1" ( 
    if "%var%" == "0" (
        goto monitoroff
    )
    if "%var%" == "1" (
        goto monitoron
    )
)
goto start
:monitoron
for /l %%x in (1, 1, 50) do (
    echo %%x
    "C:\Users\%USERNAME%\Documents\nircmd-x64\nircmd.exe" monitor on
)
set var=0
goto start 
:monitoroff
"C:\Users\%USERNAME%\Documents\nircmd-x64\nircmd.exe" cmdwait 1 monitor off
set var=1
goto start
```

here is where the problem appears. My code freezes after

```
for /F "delims=" %%K in ('xcopy /W "%~F0" "%~F0" ^< COM4 2^> NUL') do (
   if not defined key set "key=%%K"
)
```

This confuses me because when I run this code on my arduino

```
void setup() {
   Serial.begin(115200);

}

void loop() {
    int var = 0;
    Serial.print(var);
}
```

my batch file echos 0 and everything runs smoothly. I dont see the difference between the two Arduino codes. Any help would be great

Comment: Using a batch file to monitor serial port messages is not something i have ever seen attempted before. It is unlikely to work robustly if ever. Suggest you implement a coninuously running program in e.g. Python, using pyserial.

Comment: Thanks for responding and I did end up using pyserial to monitor it